# Find element and click using VBA Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I was trying to select the highlighted Xpath in this Photo below.
Afterwards I was trying to click on the element.

Code trials:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Element = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*a[@data-id='_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P']")
Set Element1 = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*/div/a[contains(@data-id,'_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P')]]")
test = Element1.Value
Element.Click
Element1.Click
Set Element3 = GC.FindElementByCss("a[data-id='_VIEW--OPEN_BY_CODE_P']")
Element3.Click
GC.FindElementById("_VIEW--OPEN_BY_CODE_P").Click
```

But on both tryouts I wasn't able to do it. First Element is Empty second Element not.

The element is at the bottom and is the blue highlighted line.

[image]

PS: I hoped there is some unknown thing like an Iframe which you can solve by switch to. Perhaps this "<!--->".

HTML Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Set Element = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*/a[@data-id='_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P']")`? Note the `/` after `*`.

Comment: Yes now, but this Element is also empty.

Comment: `GC.FindElementByXPath("//*/*[contains(@text, 'All Complaints by Number')]") `  For what i can see, there probably is an empty element with the exact same locator as is currently used. Check if this approach works. This way it would only start with the non-empty element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close enough. Given the snapshot of the HTML there is no [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). The element:

[image: VIEW--OPEN_BY_CODE_P]

is within an `<a>` tag with *data-id* attribute as *`_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P`* and *text* as *`All Complaints by Number`*

---

### Solution

To locate the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  Set Element = GC.FindElementByCss("a[data-id='_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* and *data-id* attribute:

  ```
  Set Element = GC.FindElementByXPath("//a[@data-id='_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* and the text *All Complaints by Number*:

  ```
  Set Element = GC.FindElementByXPath("//a[text()='All Complaints by Number']")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* *data-id* attribute and the text *All Complaints by Number*:

  ```
  Set Element = GC.FindElementByXPath("//a[@data-id='_VIEW--ALL_COMPLAINTS_VIEW_P' and text()='All Complaints by Number']")
  ```